# jQuery css() function does not work with css property columns (dynamic content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I am trying to order the li tags of a dynamically loaded list in two columns. With a static list, this can be easily achieved by using css

```
ul {
   columns: 2;
}
```

But how can I achieve this effect with a dynamically loaded list that I load in with jQuery? Here is the code snippet that loads the content (#list-right is the list the li tags of which are loaded dynamically):

```
$.post('list_right.php', {lan: $('#select_1').val()}, function (data) {
    $('#list-right').html(data);
});
```

I have tried this:

```
$('#list-right').html(data).css('columns', '2');
```

But that didn't work. I have also tried that:

```
$(document).on('load', '#list-right', function () {
   $('#list-right').css('columns', '2');
});
```

However, that didn't work either. So what can I do here? The dynamic list is loaded by clicking a button.

Comment: What exactly is the `#list-right` element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4axnok7g/  If it is a `ul`, it seems to work.

Comment: If you've got a CSS rule like that, it will apply to all content in the DOM, not just stuff that was there when the page loaded.

Comment: What's the content of the 'data' field?

Comment: silly question but if you `console.log($('#list-right').html())` after you fed it the data what do you get? does it return `$('#list-right')`?

Comment: #list-right is an ul that is dynamically filled with <li>something</li>. These list items are the content of data.

Comment: #list-right is indeed loaded, I even see it in #list-right, but it is not in two columns as I want it to be, that's my problem.

Comment: @AlexM, if you inspect the DOM in Chrome developer tools, do you see the style added to the ul? If so, you can look on the right hand side at the inspector and see what rule is being applied for columns

Comment: Other styles work, e. g. changing font color. But I think I know what the error is. For a very brief fraction of a second, I see the right style, but then it changes back to a one column list. I think there is something else in my code that changes it back, so I will first go trough it and see if I can fix it that way. The style seems to work after all... I hope I am not mistaken.